# Update textbox outside telerik radgrid using a value from column inside telerik radgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-grid

here is overview:
1. RadGrid is generated with values from database
2. one of columns in RadGrid is "itemtemplate checkbox column" which is unchecked on load
3. there are a textbox outside RadGrid which needs to be updated with following value (  total rows checked )

if user check a checkbox, rowcount must be updated to textbox.

kindly assist.

safie.

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution , It should be fired ASAP checkbox has been checked or unchecked.

```
function Checked() {
var grid = $find("<%=RadGrid1.ClientID %>");
var count = 0;
var masterTable = grid.get_masterTableView();
for (var i = 0; i < masterTable.get_dataItems().length; i++) {
    var gridItemElement = masterTable.get_dataItems()[i].findElement("chkToFind");
    if (gridItemElement.checked) {
        count++;
    }
}
//update the text box with count value
 txtBox.value=count;
}
```

Let me know if you have any concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

In `itemTemplate` checkbox make `auto-postback true` and `onCheckedChange event` count the number of checked rows of `Grid` and update `textbox's text` with that number. For example :

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="ToggleRowSelection" AutoPostBack="True" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Now, take a `RadAjaxManager` and Its `ajax settings` add the `gridview` and pass the `textbox` name in `UpdatedControls` pass the `textbox's Id` and `grid's Id`. For example :

```
<AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="GridId">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="TextBoxId" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="GridId" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
</AjaxSettings>
```

In .cs page

```
protected void ToggleSelectedState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Count the grid's checked rows and update texbox here.
}
```

Thanks

Comment: thanks for solutions. both @paritosh client side and side solutions doesn't work in my case. here is code for your reference:

Comment: `code` function Checked() {
            var grid = $find("<%=CurrentGrid.ClientID %>");
            var count = 0;
            var masterTable = grid.get_masterTableView();
            for (var i = 0; i < masterTable.get_dataItems().length; i++) {
                var gridItemElement = masterTable.get_dataItems()[i].findElement("lblColumn");
                if (gridItemElement.checked) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            //update the text box with count value
             txtboxID.value=count; 
            }

Comment: `code` <telerik:GridTemplateColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter column column" HeaderText="Deposited ?"
                        UniqueName="Deposit"  >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="lblColumn" runat="server"  onclick="Checked()"  >
                            </asp:CheckBox>
                             
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

Comment: Solution did not work as because I have no idea what is your real code .. I gave you an idea..